# check before Update or Insert - performance?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

Currently I have the following setup to save Data from a PHP class to a MySQL Database.

```
$old_value = SELECT from db;
$new_values = $this->get_values();

if(empty($old_value)) {
  INSERT into db
}
if($old_value != $new_value) {
  UPDATE db
}
if(empty($new_value)) {
  DELETE db
}
```

is there a better and faster way? i thought about something like "DELETE ALL old" - "INSERT EVERTHING" but this is far slower.

Comment: 1. Do you have an actuall problem with performance? 2. You could use [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) if it meets your criteria.

Comment: If you don't use table locking (either full table or just matching rows) your current method is unreliable.

Comment: What about checking if the value has changed in the update statement, like this: `UPDATE ... WHERE id = 123 AND new_value = old_value`? If the affected row count is 1, the row was updated.

Comment: ON DUPLICATE KEY and checking inside the statement do only work for updating. but what about the rows which should be deleted?
BTW: Everything is done inside a transaktion with row-based r/w locks.

Comment: if `$new_value` is empty you'll delete the whole Data?

Comment: @SparKot of course not everything. just the current row.